# How does scoping work in javascript? Why does this function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply do not understand how the "reset" function works here, and I created this script! The "value" variable on line 8...how is that reset to zero and then picked up by the iterator("value++") on the next line? I would have thought the iterator, and the whole script, was outside of the function's scope?

```
var timer = null, 
    interval = 1000,
    value = 48;

$("#start").click(function() {
  if (timer !== null) return;
  timer = setInterval(function () {
      $("#reset").click(function() { value = 0} );
      value++;
      $("#input").val(value);
  }, interval); 
});

$("#stop").click(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qHL8Z/147/)

Comment: FYI: jQuery is not the language, javascript is.

Comment: Everytime you bind that click function in that setInterval, I just want you to know it has to bind another click event all together, so regardless `$('#input').val()` will always be `1`, and, more than that, it's going to fire countless times. [Here's the idea visualized](http://jsfiddle.net/GNSDp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your var `value` is accessible by all other functions inside that function
(the `document ready`  in your case (if you have it at all, otherwise it's totally a global var name.)). 
Another way is to define your `var` to the `window` Object** which will make it also global to all outer and other functions

Examples with the "usual" way and with some *Immediately Invoked Functions Expressions* to see clearly the difference:

```
var text = "Hello!"; // Global

(function sayhello(){
   alert(text); // Ok, works
})();
```

---

http://jsbin.com/apuker/2/edit

```
(function defineVar(){
  var text = "Hello!"; // Private
})();

(function sayhello(){
   alert(text); // No dice
})();
```

---

http://jsbin.com/apuker/4/edit

```
(function defineVar(){
  window.text = "Hello!";
})();

(function sayhello(){
   alert(text); // Watta?... IT WORKS!
})();
```

---

and BTW, Your code should look like: <sub>(note the `#reset` and the nicer `if (timer) return;`)</sub>

```
var timer = null, 
    interval = 1000,
    value = 48;

$("#start").click(function() {
  if (timer) return;           // return - if timer is not null (true).
  timer = setInterval(function () {
      value++;
      $("#input").val(value);
  }, interval); 
});

$("#reset").click(function() {
    value = 0;
});

$("#stop").click(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer=null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roko. Could you explain exactly what the " if (timer) return " line is doing?

Comment: @Starkers You're already setting `timer` to `null`. If you pass `null` into an `if` condition the result will be a boolean `false` if `null`, and will be `true` if (else). So to resume this line says if `timer` is NOT `''||0||undefined||false||null||NaN` (exists) --> return (exit click function immediately) --> else continue. So this line will return the function if it has: `if (true) return;`

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you don't even need any fancy explanations involving closures or binding.

You've defined `value` with global scope. The function passed to `setInterval` repeatedly increments that value and updates the `#input` element, and the function bound to `#reset` sets it to zero. Both functions have access to variables with global scope.

Comment: Those variables are not in global scope since he has selected the option where jsfiddle wraps your code in a function, see `view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/qHL8Z/147/show/`

Comment: @Esailija with the fiddle since he has domReady selected obviously its not global there.  But since the code is posted here as it is, I think we can assume that that is the intent, otherwise the jsfiddle code that wraps it would have been posted here.

Comment: @marteljn sure but it still invalidates this answer

Comment: The answer applies to the text available here, which is all that most visitors will read, and may be all that the asker had in mind anyway. But for the curious: variables referenced by javascript functions, in their defining contexts, are "bound" into the new function's context so that they continue to be available when called later. This is called lexical scoping. This is a reasonable tutorial: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/picking-up-javascript-closures-and-lexical-scoping

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `value` is defined at the global scope so it can be accessed anywhere. So upon clicking the element `reset`, the global `value` is set back to 0.

Changing it to:

```
$("#reset").click(function() { var value = 0} );
```

would create a seperate `value` variable scoped only to that function.

Comment: but then that new variable would be useless, as no one could use it.

Comment: @JuanGuerrero obviously, it was an example to illustrate how variables can be scoped to functions.

Comment: Those variables are not in global scope since he has selected the option where jsfiddle wraps your code in a function, see `view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/qHL8Z/147/show/`

Answer (score 0):

As of ECMAScript 5, there is only function scope. All variables are global by default, unless declared using the 'var' keyword in which case they are only visible in the function they were declared.

In your script, although you declare 'value' using the var keyword, you declare it outside of any function effectively making it a global variable.

FYI:
There are currently plans to introduce the ability to declare variables with block scope in ECMAScript 6 via the new 'let' keyword.